# Calculating a weighted average for a group

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I have a reports similar to the following:

[image]

I need it to look like the following:

[image]

The report is grouped by Department. I cannot figure out how to create the formula field YTD AVG to calculate and show in each group footing and then reset for the next group.

I understand the calculation for the YTD AVG, for example YTD AVG for dept1 would be:

((80*100)+(100*40)) / (100+40)

I just don't know how to get it in Crystal Reports.

Comment: The solution depends on how you're currently getting the Average and the NumberOfResponses. Are they from Crystal's Sum() and Average() summary functions, or are they coming straight from the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Crystal's weighted average summary function:

1. Insert a summary, and select the group footer
2. Select the database field containing the average
3. Select **Weighted average with**
4. Select the field containing the number of responses

Answer (score 1):

Create a formula called 'Month_Total' and place it in the details section for each row/month and suppress it `{month.average} * {month.responses}` In your example, this will give you the "(80*100)" and "(100*40)" portions.

Create another formula called 'Department_Avg' and place it in the department group footer section `sum({@Month_Total},{month.month_name}) / sum({month.responses},{month.month_name})`

The second parameter to Sum() should match whatever department-related field you're already grouping on and specifies that you want to sum only over the individual groups. This will give you your entire YTD calculation for each group/department.

Comment: this will definitely help me understand formula fields better